# Typescript Advanced Types to Validate Specific Objects

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm trying to create a number of types to be able to write:

1. ***MyObjectDetails*** — defines MyObject structure
2. ***MyObject*** - object that correctly follows these MyObjectDetails.

```
// Details example
const testObjectDetails: MyObjectDetails = {
    name: 'Test',
    fields: [
        {
            name: 'property1'
        },
        {
            name: 'property2'
        }
    ]
}

// Object example
const testObject: MyObject<typeof testObjectDetails> = {
    property1: 123,
    property3: 456 // Should throw Error -> no such field in the details 
    // Should throw Error -> property2 is missing
}
```

I wrote some code, but they it's not working as expected:

```
type MyField = string extends infer T ? Readonly<{
  name: T
}> : never

type MyObjectDetails = Readonly<{
  name: string,
  fields: ReadonlyArray<MyField>
}>

type MyObject<T extends MyObjectDetails> = {
    [K in T['fields'][number]['name']]: any;
}
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is the declaration of `testObjectDetails`. You are declaring it with the type `MyObjectDetails`. When you do this, all type information about specific properties is lost because `MyObjectDetails` does not contain details about specific property names.

One way to solve this would be to use `as const` and remove the type `MyObjectDetails`.

```
const testObjectDetails = {
    name: 'Test',
    fields: [
        {
            name: 'property1'
        },
        {
            name: 'property2'
        }
    ]
} as const
```

If you still want to have type safety when declaring the `testObjectDetails` object, you need to use a factory function:

```
const testObjectDetails = createTestObjectDetails({
    name: 'Test',
    fields: [
        {
            name: 'property1'
        },
        {
            name: 'property2'
        }
    ]
} as const)


function createTestObjectDetails<T extends MyObjectDetails>(testObjDetails: T) : T{
  return testObjDetails
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But what if I need to keep the type. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: I edited my answer with a different approach